# Split string once on the first whitespace in Rust

Tags: string, rust, split, whitespace

I have a string, say `"dog cat fish"`, that I want to split on the first whitespace into two slices that look like this: `("dog", "cat fish")`.
I tried to naively use the `split_once()` method like this:

```rust
let string = "dog cat fish";
let (first_word, rest_of_string) = string.split_once(' ').unwrap();
```

It works effectively for regular whitespace characters. However, I would like it to work also for other types of Unicode whitespace characters like `\t` as the `split_whitespace()` method does.
I don't want to use `split_whitespace()`, though, because it returns an iterator and I would have to recollect and join the words after iterating, as it would be a waste of time:

```rust
let mut it = string.split_whitespace();
let first_word = it.next().unwrap();
let rest_of_string = it.collect::Vec<&str>().join(" ");
```

So, in case I had a string like `"dog \t cat fish"`, how could I split it to obtain these two slices `("dog", "cat fish")`?
I also thought of using regular expressions, but is there a better method?

Comment: `split_once` can be called with any type with the trait [`Pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html). So you can provide a slice of chars `[' ','\t','\r','\n']` or a predicate that returns true on whitespace as argument. Or a regular expression - which should be comparable to the slice of chars solution.

Comment: `SplitWhitespace` objects have an unstable `remainder()` method, but you still need to `trim_start()` the remainder, since it includes the leading whitespace. (And of course it currently only works on Nightly.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could `split_once` with a function that calls `char::is_whitespace()`, but that will only split on the first whitespace. You'll then need to trim the second `&str` from the start.

```
fn main() {
    let string = "dog \t cat fish";
    let (a, b) = string.split_once(char::is_whitespace).unwrap();
    let b = b.trim_start();
    dbg!(a, b);
}
```

Output:

```
[src/main.rs:5] a = "dog"
[src/main.rs:5] b = "cat fish"
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=33a27b5a3b94183907b4722e277ad40c)

Answer (score 1):

Of course @Dogbert is right.

I just wanted to add that it would also be quite straight-forward to implement this yourself using `.char_indices()`:

```rust
fn split_whitespace(s: &str) -> Option<(&str, &str)> {
    let mut iter = s.char_indices();

    let whitespace_start;
    let whitespace_end;

    loop {
        let (pos, ch) = iter.next()?;
        if ch.is_whitespace() {
            whitespace_start = pos;
            break;
        }
    }

    loop {
        let (pos, ch) = iter.next()?;
        if !ch.is_whitespace() {
            whitespace_end = pos;
            break;
        }
    }

    Some((&s[..whitespace_start], &s[whitespace_end..]))
}

fn main() {
    let string = "dog \t\rcat fish";
    println!("{:?}", split_whitespace(string).unwrap());
}
```

```
("dog", "cat fish")
```

Note that there is no faster way to split a string than to iterate over all of its characters, because characters in a Rust string are variable in size due to the fact that Rust Strings are UTF-8 encoded.